# what I am doing wrong with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me and tell me what is is wrong with code.
please help me with this code. I don't know what is wrong with that.
Can anyone help me and tell me what is is wrong with code.
please help me with this code. I don't know what is wrong with that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo">enter code here</p>
    <script>
        var all = [
            {
                "name": "redfruit",
                "price": 9.20,
                "text2": "Our selection of red fruits and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
            },
            {
                "name": "veggie",
                "price": 8.80,
                "text2": "Our selection of veggies and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
            },
            {
                "name": "jajko",
                "price": 6.90,
                "text2": "Our selection of veggies and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
            }
        ];

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            var moko = all[i];
            var extrahtml = '\
            <li>\
                    <div class="info">\
                        <h3>' + moko.name + '</h3>\
                        <p>' + moko.price.toFixed(2) + ' </p>\
                        <p>' + moko.text2 + '</p>\

            '</div>\
                    </li>\
            ';

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += extrahtml;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you show us what the HTML page looks like? What do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

see below updated, you missed/misplaced the single quote , I hope this is what you are looking for :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">enter code here</p>

<script>
    var all = [
        {
            "name": "redfruit",
            "price": 9.20,
            "text2": "Our selection of red fruits and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
        },
        {
            "name": "veggie",
            "price": 8.80,
            "text2": "Our selection of veggies and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
        },
        {
            "name": "jajko",
            "price": 6.90,
            "text2": "Our selection of veggies and fresh milk<br>No added preservatives or sugars"
        }
    ];

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        var moko = all[i];
        var extrahtml = '\
    <li>\
            <div class="info">\
                <h3>' + moko.name + '</h3>\
                <p>' + moko.price.toFixed(2) + ' </p>\
                <p>' + moko.text2 + '</p>\
                </div>\
            </li>\
    ';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += extrahtml;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer would be much more valuable with explanations of exactly what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: added the comment .